# Dudas sobre el uso de los entornos de Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

Muy buenas. Tengo duda respecto a los entornos de anaconda, verán estoy en primer semestre de ingeniería en sistemas, usamos bastantes librerías como numpy, etc, así que tengo instalado los entornos de anaconda. Mi duda seria que si dentro de los entornos de anaconda solo puedo descargar librerías de anaconda o puedo usar pip3 e instalar una librería como pygame por ejemplo dentro de un entorno de anaconda.

Es decir, puedo instalar una librería diferente de las pertenecientes a anaconda, dentro de un entorno, y solo dentro de ese entorno y ¿cómo podría hacerlo?

PD: estoy consiente de los entornos virtuales de Python, pero es lo que quiero evitar usar, quiero trabajar en un mismo lugar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, puedes usar `pip` o algun canal de anaconda para instalar librerías. Basta con entrar al enviroment y hacer la instalacion por ejemplo:

```
pip install rasa
```

Anaconda es una distribución de Python para la ciencia de datos. Realmente te recomiendo trabajar con `enviroments` en vez de evitarlos pues es una de las mejores ventajas que ofrece anaconda. Usar enviroments te permite trabajar en múltiples proyectos y tener en cada uno una versión especifica de python y los paquetes o modulos que necesitas. Si quieres trabajar en un solo lugar a la larga te causara problemas o incompatibilidad entre paquetes y sus versiones.

Al momento de instalar anaconda tienes 2 checkbox que puedes marcar:

1. Elegir anaconda como el interprete default de python
2. Agregar `conda` al path

El primer checkbox lo que hace es que al momento de ejecutar python se utilice el interprete que viene ya instalado en anaconda. Esta opción viene marcada por defecto por lo que en casi todos los casos esta activada. Para corroborar si estas usando el inteprete python de anaconda puedes escibir en la cmd: `python`.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Al usar el interprete de anaconda estas trabajando automaticamente en un enviroment de conda llamado `base`, este es el enviroment global de anaconda (aunque no te recomiendo trabajar directamente ahí). Si escribes `conda env list` veras los enviroments que tienes creados. En cada uno de esos enviroments puedes tener diferentes versiones de python y diferentes paquetes. Una vez que estés trabajando dentro de un enviroment puedes instalar paquetes que quieras ya sea por `pip` o usando uno de los canales de anaconda.

Docs conda channels:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html

Docs conda envs:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html